# change variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I've got this integral.

```
(1/(x2 - x1))*Integrate[\[Gamma]/(x^(1/2)*(x/t + \[Gamma]/x^(1/2))), {x, x1, x2}]
```

```
1/(x2 - x1) \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(x1\), \(x2\)]\(
\*FractionBox[\((
\*FractionBox[\(\[Gamma]\), 
SuperscriptBox[\((x)\), \(1/2\)]])\), \((
\*FractionBox[\(x\), \(t\)] + 
\*FractionBox[\(\[Gamma]\), 
SuperscriptBox[\((x)\), \(1/2\)]])\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)
```

I want to change variables to

```
u = Sqrt[x]/(\[Gamma]*t)^(1/3)
```

I wonder what would the upper bound and lower  bound be? and what is the correct result of the Integral explicitly.
I don't want to use  `IntegrateChangeVariables` command in Mathematica.

The result I've got from a book is this< which I think is wrong:

```
1/(u1^2 - 
  u2^2) (2/3^(1/2) ArcTan[(2*u1 - 1)/3^(1/2)] - 
   2/3^(1/2) ArcTan[(2*u2 - 1)/3^(1/2)] + 
   1/3 Log[((1 + u1)^2*(1 - u2 + u2^2))/((1 + u2)^2*(1 - u1 + u1^2))])
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use `IntegrateChangeVariables`, which is meant to do exactly what you want?

Comment: because I want to check it with the result written and gives sth different.

Comment: Please write the integral in a way that is readable and executable, such as InputForm.